# How to make users select their friends and post on their wall in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I know this has been asked several times before, but Facebook changes its api often so comes the necessity to ask this question again.

I have an iframe application, how to make users select their friends and post on their wall the message which comes out of my application in facebook using FB.ui ? or some other better method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is via the "send" widget. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

If you have the stream_publish right from the user, you can also fetch his friends, let the user selects the friends he wishes to post to, and than in a loop you post to this users via graph api on the wall. (without the stream_publish right, you would have to open a fb.ui for EACH of the friends the user wants to post to.

Comment: Hi Rufinus,

Thanks. Can you show me code snippet on how to use stream_publish with graph api?

Answer (score 0):

for share to friend:

```
            FB.ui({
                method: "apprequests",
                display: "iframe",
                message: 'take a tour to my app',
                data: '123'
            });
```

for post to wall:

```
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://myapp.com',
            display: 'iframe',
            message: 'take a tour to my app',
            name: 'Click to view my app',
            caption: 'Hello my app'

        });
```

Comment: Hi moguzalp, Will "apprequests" method allow a user of my app to post to his friend's wall or it will just send a request to his friend ?

Comment: How can I get the user id of the friend? Is there any custom friend selector which allows me to get the friend's UID when my user click the profile pic through some popup ?

Comment: I used jqery friend selecter for this purpose and it works perfect !!
Here it is,
http://mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html